# systemctl access denied when root

Tags: centos, administrator, systemctl

When I run

```
sudo systemctl disable avahi-daemon.socket
```

I get

```
Failed to execute operation: Access denied
```

But it's run as root, how can access be denied? (CentOS 7)

Comment: Are you running in a container, like Docker or LXC or LXD? Do you *know for sure* you are or are not in a container?

Comment: I'm running a fresh CentOS install in VirtualBox. Does that count as a container?

Comment: No, VirtualBox isn't a container, it's a virtual machine. They're fundamentally different. Most likely you need to run `journalctl -xe` to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: Note that this error message ("Failed to execute operation: Access denied") can also occur when trying to access a non-existing service in enforcing mode. In permissive mode, you would get "Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory".

Answer (score 38):

I also work on CentOS 7, and had a similar issue:

```
# systemctl unmask tmp.mount
Failed to execute operation: Access denied
```

The denial has to do with SELinux. This can be your case if you are running SELinux in `enforcing` mode:

```
# getenforce
Enforcing
```

In my case, the `systemctl` error had produced an `USER_AVC` denial in SELinux log file, `/var/log/audit/audit.log`:

```
type=USER_AVC msg=audit(1475497680.859:2656): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='avc:  denied  { enable } for auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 path="/dev/null" cmdline="systemctl unmask tmp.mount" scontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:object_r:null_device_t:s0 tclass=service  exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" sauid=0 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
```

#### Solution

[This article](https://major.io/2015/09/18/systemd-in-fedora-22-failed-to-restart-service-access-denied) states that it is due to a bug in systemd, and provides a work around:

```
systemctl daemon-reexec
```

#### Secondary solution

If the above did not work, you can set SELinux mode to `permissive`:

```
setenforce 0
```

and it should work fine. However, this 2nd solution has security implications.

Comment: I get no output instead of `Removed symlink` and afterwards `systemctl disable avahi-daemon.socket` fails as before, producing the same line in `audit.log`

Comment: Can you try to disable selinux enforce mode? `setenforce 0`

Comment: `systemctl disable avahi-daemon.socket` succeeds after `setenforce 0` without `systemctl daemon-reexec` (and I realise now the `unmask` is your command, not mine :-)) Is it okay to just do this and `setenforce 1` after?

Comment: @spraff I don't know, I'm a SELinux newbie ha ha. Imma mention `setenforce 0` in my answer then.

Comment: @spraff you can run `setenforce 1` after. that resets it to enforce.

Comment: Please don't `setenforce 0`. This is a bad practice in production environment. Please use `systemctl daemon-reexec` instead.

Comment: `systemctl daemon-reexec` worked on RHEL 7.4.

Comment: `systemctl daemon-reexec` did not work for me, I'm on fedora 28.  `setenforce 0` did work.  Normally I'm against these security hacks but I'm swimming in my own hair out of frustration with working with nonsense apis such as 'daemon-reexec' and 'setenforce 0'.  What does `setenforce 0` do?  Why it sets the enforce status to permissive of course!

Comment: Tried to upgrade lubuntu 18.10 to lubuntu 20.04 and had this error with `whoopsi` service. The `systemctl daemon-reexec` did the trick, thanks :)

Comment: @Younes and if `systemctl daemon-reexec` doesn't work?

Answer (score 33):

In my case, I had just upgraded `systemd` and any `systemctl` command was failing:

```
# systemctl daemon-reexec
Failed to reload daemon: Access denied
# systemctl status
Failed to read server status: Access denied
```

However according to the `init` manpage, you can do the same thing by sending `SIGTERM` to the daemon running as PID 1, which worked:

```
kill -TERM 1
```

This reloaded the daemon, after which all the `systemctl` commands started working again.

Comment: Thanks. Solved my problem I had after upgrading an archlinux distro after a long time.

Comment: worked on Ubuntu 18.10 - Thanks!

Comment: Same issue while force dist-upgrading ubuntu cosmic. Worked, thx.

Comment: It worked on Ubuntu 20.04 (upgraded from 18.10) and saved me a ton of headaches.
Bundle of thanks

Comment: I got the same issue. I upgraded my OS and then systemctl did not work for me. And this helps. Thanks. My version is centOS 8.

Answer (score 4):

Neither solution worked for me. It turned out there was a missing = sign on one of the lines in my .service file.  I discovered this by looking /var/log/messages and saw an error there that was more descriptive.   So the Access Denied was misleading. It was not a really a security problem.

Comment: You should provide more detail on how you solve this question.  For instance you talk about a more verbose error message, but do not indicate, what the error messag was exactly.  Without this information, this would be better served as a comment, because this answer without this information is incomplete.

Comment: which log file showed the message?

Comment: It appears this is triggered by any invalid syntax in the file (not just the = as you mention). Double check your service files for errors if you see this.